# c++ visual studio 2012 #include doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I just downloaded Visual Studio 2012 and tried my first programm with c++ but it doesn't work and I have no idea why. I hope someone can help me.

This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>



int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
std::cout << "HelloWorld\n";
system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

When I tried to compile the programm, there is the following on the console:

```
1>  HelloWorld.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\climits(5): fatal error C1083: File (Include) could not be opened: "yvals.h": No such file or directory
```

Also when I put the mouse on "cout" it says: Error "namespace ""std"" has no member ""cout""

Has anybody an idea what is the problem and how I can fix this?

Comment: Please stop using `system("pause")`. *Please*.

Comment: Your VS install is broken, yvals.h is an important #include file.  Repairing VS is the usual advice.  If you had a beta of VS installed on your machine previously or used a preview that you didn't uninstall properly then a very thorough cleanup is usually required.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of project have you created? For simple console applications, I strongly recommend "empty project". Then add a hello.cpp file to your project and paste following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world\n";
    std::cin.peek();
}
```

That should work, I've done it a dozen times. If it doesn't work, tell us the error messages.

Comment: This is not helpful, it doesn't suddenly make yvals.h appear.